# Public facing webfolder Google malware warning

Tags: asp.net, security

OS: Windows

Programming: C#, asp.net

I have a website that has a fileupload control and all the user uploaded files are stored in a folder on the server. This folder is NOT indexable by search engines and not viewable as a url (or file list view). From time to time I get a message from google webmaster tools that this folder has malware. As this folder is for uploading files, I have little control on its contents.

I wonder, there are so many websites out there which allow users to upload files.

- What are the best practices.
- Any tips to just avoid that Google keeps blacklisting this folder from time to time?

Thanks a lot in advance,
Prasad.

Answer (score 0):

Are the files then referenced in links on your webpage or sitemap.xml? Google will find them afterwards, when indexing pages where the files are referenced.

Did you find the malware files? What file extensions had they? Can you restrict the users to upload only certain (possibly safe) file types?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jozef. The files are actually manipulated on the server (like compressed for example) and then presented as a download link to the user. The file names are restricted to images, pdf's, word files and excel files. However, there is one particular case, where I allow Zip files to be uploaded. This could be a potential cause. (Google shows me zip file as a sample of malware content.

Comment: Unless you are able to run antivirus on zip files, I would highly recommend not allowing zip files to be uploaded. There are nice solutions for user to comfortable upload multiple files at the same time, so unless you require them to create some folder structure in the zip file, I would try to disallow that.